# What regex expression do I use to whitelist certain modules?

Tags: regex, ace-editor

I'm making a custom text editor and I want to write a regular expression that flags any imports/modules in javascript that I have whitelisted. For example I want it to be okay to import assert or crypto, or even both. I also want to account for aliases, importing using both "import" and "require". I'm using Ace Editor, which uses regex, to write a new rule to do so.

I'm messing around in RegEx but I can't quite get it. Here's what I have so far:

```
"^import (?!(?:assert|crypto)\s*;*$)\w+"
```

Comment: Why a regex? Parse the JS to an AST and look for the require function calls/import statements.

Comment: I'm using Ace Editor, which uses regex, to write a new rule

Comment: That kind of context and constraint is useful to include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what might be the desired outputs, guessing that you maybe trying to design an expression somewhat similar to:

```
^import(?!\s+(\bassert\b|\bcrypto\b)).*;\s*$
```

#### DEMO

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HOzHOv/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]